# how to avoid inheritance of <site> and <url> from Maven parent POM?

Tags: maven

**This question has no Maven multi module context**
In my projects, I often use a parent POM which defines some Maven plugins.

```xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>commonParent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>   </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>  </snapshotRepository>
        <site>
            <id>releases</id>
            <url>dav:http://intra.nexus.de/repository/company-docs/${artifactId}</url>
        </site>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

I have a small documentation for this parent POM, which is deployed to Nexus 3 using the maven site plugin. Works fine.

I use this parent in other projects (packaging war and jar), which have a documentation, too. And they have their own `<site>` and `<url>` elements:

```xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>commonParent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>  </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>      </snapshotRepository>
        <site>
            <id>releases</id>
            <url>dav:http://intra.nexus.de/repository/company-docs/${artifactId}</url>
        </site>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

When I deploy the site with `mvn site:deploy`, I get this output:

```
Pushing D:\dev\myProject\target\site
to http://intra.nexus.de/repository/company-docs/commonParent../myProject`
```

**How can I avoid the inheritance of `<site>` from the parent to my project?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/usage.html) of Maven Site Plugin:

> If subprojects inherit the site URL from a parent POM, they will automatically append their  to form their effective deployment location.

But, as soon as the parent project is not the direct ancestor, Maven will generated inadequate url and site/url values. 
E.g. with a parent project which is not the root project.